# add elements of a vector to elements of a list in R

Tags: r, loops

I have a simple list and a simple vector of the same length. I would like to add the `ith` element of the vector to the `ith` element of the list. Is there a way to do better than with this for loop?

```
test <- list(element1=list(a=1,b=2,a1=8),
             element2=list(a=9,d=17))
vec <- c(12,25)

for (i in 1:length(test)){
    test[[i]] <- c(test[[i]],vec[i])
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Use the multivariate equivalent of `sapply`, i.e. `mapply`. In the code below, the function `c` is applied to the first elements of each `test` and `vec`, then the second elements, etc...

```
test = mapply(c, test, vec)
```

Comment: thanks so much. I was so close when I tried lapply but did not get it to work. Glad you helped out.

Comment: is there a way to give a same fixed name to both of the appended list elements? I tried to get something to work with `"names<-"` and `mapply`

Comment: You have to coerce `vec` into a list of named elements, then you can use `lapply` and `names<-`. For example ``mapply(c,test,lapply(as.list(vec), `names<-`, 'boo'))``

Comment: @hans0l0 Yes, you can do it all with one command: `mapply(function(x,y) c(x, "yourname" = y), test, vec)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can allways translate for loop into lapply/apply/sapply. Here is example for your code.

```
"for"(i, 1:length(test), test[i] <- c(test[[i]], vec[i]))

test <- lapply(1:length(test), function(i) c(test[[i]], vec[i]))
```